# navigation with in a building navigate from living room to study room ios

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation

i want to develop an iphone app based on gps navigation.
i have an idea about how to navigate user from a location to other location (that covers distance in km). but i am totally lost how it can be done if distance is very near like with in a building. for example navigate from living room to your study room.
Any idea about this would be a great.

as per knowledge i think i will have to have all geo points of building and all tiles images of building

is it possible? if yes then how i should start with it.

thanks for giving your time to read this qns.

Comment: let us know wats your idea to to navigate user from a location to other location (that covers distance in km). May be that can help to find some solution

Comment: i am taking user's current location geo point and giving an opportunity to user to enter their desire destination. then i calculate the equivalent geo point corresponding to entered location. then i draw a route between those geo points

Comment: how you get  equivalent geo point corresponding to entered location and all. show some code.

Comment: there is a google api which needs name of location you can pass that and can get the geo point of desired location